# Nuxeo Vision package not working in Nuxeo Platform

Tags: google-vision, nuxeo

I'm new to Nuxeo Platform. I want to integrate Nuxeo vision to my Nuxeo Platform running on a windows machine. I had installed Nuxeo Vision package and also added google API Credentials to nuxeo.conf file.
nuxeo.conf File:

```
org.nuxeo.vision.google.credential=C:\Nuxeo\bin\my-project-nuxeo-245511-77a94e04462e.json"
```

In documentation they told it will work by default, but it's not working for me. Can anyone help me with this?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/a4681fbefbd442d88652268beab20e0b/My-Nuxeo-Car-doesn-t-start-1

Comment: I tot you know about Nuxeo Vision.https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/nuxeo-vision/